# Galois group vs Permutation subgroups.[Confusion]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Okay my main problem rest with this quote from Rotmans group theory:

> Not every permutation of the roots of a polynomial $f(x)$ need correspond to some $\sigma\in Gal(K/F)$

but then he uses the example

> Let $f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)\in Q[x].$ Every $\sigma\in Gal(Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/Q)$ must permute $\{\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}\},$ **but it is plain there is no such $\sigma$ with $\sigma(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{3}$**

My question why can $\sigma$ in the example not be automorphism of $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ that fixes $Q$.

Assuming $a,b,c,d\in Q$, what part of $\sigma(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})=a+b\sqrt{3}+c\sqrt{2}+d\sqrt{6}$ isn't an automorphism and doesn't fix $Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $$2=\sigma(2)=\sigma(\sqrt{2}^2)\neq\sigma(\sqrt{2})^2=\sqrt{3}^2=3$$

So $\sigma$ isn't even a ring homomorphism. Just a homomorphism of the vector space structure over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I am an idiot. I was so obvious. @Eoin

Comment: @user160110 Nope! I had this problem too at some point haha.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma$ is an automorphism, then you must have
$\sigma(\sqrt{2})^2 = \sigma(\sqrt{2}^2) = \sigma(2) = 2$, but $\sqrt{3}^2 = 3 \neq 2$, so $\sigma(\sqrt{2}) \neq \sqrt{3}$

Comment: Thank you, again I am a bit negligent for not noticing this. @rob-arthan

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $\alpha$ satisfies $f(\alpha) = a_n\alpha^n + a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} + \dots a_0 = 0$, then $$0 = \sigma(f(\alpha)) = f(\sigma(\alpha))$$ so $\sigma(\alpha)$ is also a root of $f$. We can choose the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ for $f$ which is $x^2 - 2$. The converse also holds to some degree.

Comment: are you saying that $\sigma$ simply permutes the roots of $f(x)?$ Because I could grasp that fact, it was the whole " Certain permutations fail to generate field automorphisms." thing that I couldn't understand. @Asvin

Comment: No, any permutation has to take roots of a polynomial to other roots of the polynomial. $x^2-2$ does not have $\sqrt 3$ as a root.